# How to do a fixed effects regression with interaction effect and lags in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, panel-data

I have panel data over the period 2010-2020 for 10 different regions in a country. I would like to measure the effect of **X1** on **Y** were **Y** is the share of the population who voted for a extreme right party at Year *s*, and **X1** is the share of asylum seekers in the region at Year *s*. I would like to measure the effect of **X1** on **Y** during a specific year when asylum seekers in all regions increased drastically to examine if the increase in asylum seekers had any effect on the share of the population who voted on the extreme right party. X2...Xn are a bunch of control variables.

I have found the package "fixest" and can run a normal FE-regression, but cant seem to understand how to include an interaction effect with a specific year (the "treatment" year, when asylum seekers increased in all regions) for X1.

This is an example of the equation im trying to estimate:
[FE regression model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBGQD.png), where (1) RHS term is region fixed effects, (2) RHS term is year fixed effects, (3) RHS term is the interaction between the year 2016 and asylum seekers in the previous year, (4) RHS term is all the control variables and (5) RHS term is the error term.

Below is a made up head of the data frame.

```
Year   Region   Y      X1    X2...Xn
2010   A        0.15  0.001
2011   A        0.25  0.05
.      .        .     .
.      .        .     .
2010   B        0.09  0.002
2011   B        0.14  0.04
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use the function `i()` to create an interaction between a continuous variables (x1) and a factor (the year). With `i`'s argument `keep`, you can select the year you want to keep.

The second thing is the lag: just use the function `l()` within a `fixest` estimation, but it requires to specify the panel identifiers.

Here's an example of the expected behavior, it should be easy to adapt to your case:

```
library(fixest)

data(base_did)
est = feols(y ~ i(l(x1), period, keep = 10) | id + period, base_did, panel.id = ~id+period)
#> NOTE: 108 observations removed because of NA values (RHS: 108).
est
#> OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: y
#> Observations: 972 
#> Fixed-effects: id: 108,  period: 9
#> Standard-errors: Clustered (id) 
#>                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) 
#> l(x1, 1):period::10 -0.263237   0.217412 -1.2108 0.228651 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> RMSE: 4.8876     Adj. R2: 0.173257
#>                Within R2: 0.002642
```

Comment: Thanks!! Does i(l(x1), period, keep = 10) indicate an interaction with the x1 and period variable at period = 10 and x1 = one year before (i.e. year 9)?

Also, would you know why I am getting different results from plm and fixest when running these regressions:
plm <- plm(y ~ x1, data = df, index = c("id", "period"), model = "within")
fixest <- feols(y ~ x1 | id + period, df, panel.id = ~id+period)

I want the model to include region fixed effects and year fixed effects and I want the standard errors to be clustered at a region level, with robust SE. Thanks!

Comment: First Q: yes `l(x1, 1):period::10` means lag(x1) x period == 10. 2nd Q: the difference with plm is normal, plm does not include year FEs in the within estimator. One remark: panel.id in fixest is only needed if you have lag in the model.  2nd Remark: by default the SEs will be clustered wrt the first FE, so if you first include regions FEs you're fine. Otherwise, just use the arg. cluster.

Comment: you should mark this as the accepted answer OP